# Conditional variable in classic mode

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to achieve conditional logic in Azure pipeline in `classic` mode instead of `YAML` format

I can see an YAML property `condition:` is [introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to YAML format, however I couldn't find the same is available in classic mode for **ANY** task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it in the [`Classic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic):

[image]

Find `Control Options` in a task:

[image]

Find `Additional options` in a job:

[image]

Comment: thank you. Could you please advise how to refer to a template pipeline in the classic mode?

Answer (score 1):

In the link you mentioned, switch to the [Classic tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic), and you'll see the instructions about how to use conditions in classic mode:

> Inside the Control Options of each task, and in the Additional options for a job in a release pipeline, you can specify the conditions under which the task or job will run.